# Restart lottie-animation over and over

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-lottie

I'm trying to make the lottie animation start again every time the value of the `amount` variable changes.

Changing the value for the first time is a success, but subsequent changes to the value do not trigger the animation.

```
@Composable
private fun Lottie(
    amount: Long
) {
    var oldAmount by remember { mutableStateOf(0L) }
    val currentAmount by remember { mutableStateOf(amount) }
    val playAnimation = currentAmount != amount && oldAmount != 0L
    oldAmount = currentAmount

    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
        LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.my_animation)
    )

    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition,
        isPlaying = playAnimation,
        speed = 1f,
        restartOnPlay = false,
        cancellationBehavior = LottieCancellationBehavior.OnIterationFinish
    )

    LottieAnimation(composition = composition, progress = progress)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Found solution**

Wrapping up the composable with the key element did the trick

```
...
key(amount) {
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
            LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.my_animation)
        )

        val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
            composition,
            isPlaying = playAnimation,
            speed = 1f,
            restartOnPlay = false,
            cancellationBehavior = LottieCancellationBehavior.OnIterationFinish
        )

        LottieAnimation(composition = composition, progress = progress)
    }
...
```

Comment: Nice solution, I had a similar issue, when I wrap the animation inside a LazyColumn the animation works fine but if wrap inside a Column the animation was not reset (the animation is a simple checkbox to mark complete a task). With the  key {} block and Column works perfect. Thanks for share. I will reseach more about that key block.